# Weird apostrophe issue

Tags: views, 8

Using Drupal version - 8.7.4. Added a 'Text (plain, long)' field for news summary to news content type.

There is a news view that shows all recent news items with the summary.

I created a new news item and pasted the summary from a document from Google Drive.

The apostrophe shows up as `&#039;` on the view but in the drupal edit page, it shows a `'`

Any thoughts on why this is happening? Any solutions? I am completely clueless. Thanks for reading.

Comment: It's being escaped.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor/issues/1864238) with CKEditor.

In your case, the ampersand character `&` is being escaped as `&amp;` which is causing the HTML entity for your apostrophe to appear as `&amp;#039;`.

The entity for the ampersand is well-formed, so the ampersand appears in your rendered output. But this causes the entity for the apostrophe to be malformed, so it appears as a literal string.

There's a CKEditor config that you can do to [force a simple ampersand](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.forceSimpleAmpersand), but I'm not sure how it will affect other text fields site-wide (which will no longer have their ampersands escaped), so proceed with caution.

Perhaps someone with more CKEditor experience can tell us if there's a way to configure this more narrowly.